# Is calling malloc() necessary for this example code?

Tags: c, pointers

Assume following example code:

```
//open some file

char* data[10];

for ( int i=0; !feof(file) && i < 10; i++ )
{
    fgets( data[i], 100, file );
}

//close file
```

AFAIK using a pointer array without allocating memory to individual pointers like this is unsafe and if works, it's because there happens not to be any vital information contained at that memory region.

But I have seen many people using it like this and I doubted myself.

Is this a proper use?

Comment: Please read and understand [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior and is extremely unsafe.

The elements of your `data` arrays are pointers, and their initial values are garbage. They could point to memory that's in use for some other purpose, or to memory that doesn't exist. I'd be surprised if your program didn't crash.

You don't need to call `malloc`. You could define

```
char data[10][100];
```

Furthermore, you shouldn't use `feof` to determine when you've finished reading input. `feof` returns a true value if the *previous* input function has failed due to running out of input. If there's an error other than running other than running out of input, `ferror` will return true and `feof` will not. Use the value returned by `fgets` to determine whether it succeeded.